# ionic2 ngFor firebase key in select

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor

I have the following firebase database structure[image]

I am getting my data via

```
this.selectOptions = af.database.list('/select-options');
```

My goal is to have an ionic2 (angular2) form that has 2 select inputs that map to a model and offers the select options that are the keys in the picture above.

I want to store items like below that users can create via the required form.

```
{
  item1: {
    phase: "phase1",
    place: "park"
  }, ...
}
```

I tried different things with *ngFor but can not access the keys. Maybe my database model is also "wrong". Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2), we can just do

```
selectOptions.phase.$key
```

I was having the problem with [angularfire2-offline](https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline) which strips the `$key` from the returned observable